# Help searching in files for regex patterns, recursively, with specialized output

Tags: text-processing, scripting, search, recursive

My problem is that I need to:

1. Find all lines matching `regex_pattern` in all files (deep search) in a given root directory
2. For each line that matches, output:

   - File name
   - Line number containing the match
   - Line contents
   - The regex pattern
3. Import the above data into Excel (so a CSV, or delimited output format comes to mind)

**What is the easiest way to do this task?**

For the sake of proving I thought about this somewhat, I would write a Perl script that took as input a single fully qualified filename and a regex pattern, and process the lines using the approximate Perl below (I haven't tried yet, but this is what my first attempt would resemble):

```
while (<FILE>) {
  $line_number++;

  if ($_ =~ m/regex_pattern/) {
    # output: file_name\tline_number\tregex_pattern\t$_
    # ignore escaping issues for the time being
  }
}
```

I'm still not sure how I'd pass in the contents of each directory with a recursive search into this Perl script.  I can do the searching in Perl but I'm sure there's a nice Unix/Linux way to do this.

I'm not married to Perl.  If there's a way to do it chaining together standard Unix/Linux tools, that'd be awesome.  If not, I prefer to use Perl as I'm somewhat familiar with it's syntax.

Comment: "For each line that matches, I need the following outputted" – but not the file. Interesting...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Good call, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
find /search/root -type f -exec awk 'BEGIN{pattern="regex_pattern"} $0 ~ pattern {printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",FILENAME,FNR,$0,pattern}'  {} +
```

Comment: Worked like a champ... very elegant.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
start cmd:> find . -type f -name 'search*' -exec awk -v regex=foo \
cont. cmd:>   '$0 ~ regex {print FILENAME,FNR,regex,$0 }' {} +
./searchfile1 1 foo a_foo_b
./searchfile2 1 foo foo
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, taking advantage of the [null filehandle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) which operates on command line arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
$, = "\t";  # separator added between arguments to print
while (<>) {
  if (/regex_pattern/) {
    # $ARGV contains the current file name, $. contains the current line number,
    # $_ contains the current line including its terminating newline
    print $ARGV, $., 'regex_pattern', $_;
  }
  $. = 0 if eof;  # reset the line number between files
}
```

To pass the file names to the Perl script, in ksh93 or bash ≥4 or zsh, you can use the [`**` pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-pattern-matching) to traverse subdirectories recursively. In ksh, you need to enable this pattern first with `set -o globstar`. In bash, you need to enable it with `shopt -s globstar`.

```
shopt -s globstar
name_of_perl_script **/*
```

If your shell doesn't have `**`, or if you run into a “command line too long” error, you can use `find` instead.

```
find . -type f -exec name_of_perl_script {} +
```

You can also do this by combining more specialized tools. You probably already know grep to search a pattern in files. The `-n` option makes it print the number of each matching line. Passing `/dev/null` as a file name is a trick to make sure that `grep` also prints the file name (it won't do it if there happens to be a single file on its command line).

```
grep -n 'regex_pattern' **/*
```

All that's missing is changing the separators if necessary (`grep` inserts `:` between the file name, the line number and the line content), and inserting the regex at the right place. This simple replacement job is a perfect fit for `sed`. Be sure to quote the regex properly.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n 'regex_pattern' {} + |
sed 's/^\([^:]*\)\([^:]*\)/\1\t\2\tregex_pattern\t/'
```